# Create only one page for multiple languages in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, multilingual

In SharePoint 2013, can I create one page only for multiple languages without installing language packs.

Will SharePoint publish site support it?

Comment: You can write content in any language you want (e.g. I could place Spanish content in a CEWP in a German farm). I think though to get the page to display different languages using for example a user selection (like a dropdown menu or profile setting), you may need to develop a customization